# Continuity of 1/x

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Considering this function:

$\ f(x) = \frac{k}{x}$

and interval [a,b]

0 < a < b

How can I show that it is continuous and derivable in the most simple way?

Shouldn't it be continuous because of the function being frational?

Comment: Do you know the (a) definition of continuity?

Comment: How can I write that?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? For example, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $$\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$$

Comment: ok, but where should the limit tend in this case? to a ? to b? or apoint in the middle?

Comment: I'll assume you can use the definition I just gave. So to show continuity on the interval $[a,b]$, you fix a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ and show that $\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$. Then because this point is arbitrary, we get continuity on the whole interval.

Comment: You might like to reread the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) $\ddot\smile$